# "Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1" when adding ?' parameters to my query

Tags: java, database

I have a query constructed in Java to select records, and when constructing with the values `?'`, I'm getting a missing in and out parameter. If I add only `?`, it is working properly.

Here is the query where I am setting the `?'` value:

```
AND 1=fn_contact_account(P.RECORD_ID,'?''%') AND upper( P.PERSON_ID) like ?0 ESCAPE '\' AND NOT (P.PERSON_ID='Unknown')) )
```

Comment: Your question is hard to understand at the moment. I *think* I know what's wrong, but you should put more effort into a) writing clear English; b) formatting your code separate from the text; c) providing a complete example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters aren't substituted into queries textually. I believe the simplest way to do what you want is to just use the `?` on its own for the parameter, but add any leading or trailing values to the parameter itself. For example:

```
 String sql = "SELECT NAME FROM PERSON WHERE NAME LIKE ?";
 try (PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
     // Trailing % for "starts with" behaviour
     pst.setString(1, userInput + "%");
     ...
 }
```